What does 'm' stand for in an inline function?
What's going on that makes this code work? It seems that using m in an anonymous verb (if that's what it's called) turns the verb into a postfix operator.
   1 {{ 1 + m }}
2

If I replace the m with y or x, I get a syntax error. Can't find anything referencing this on the J wiki.

From the wiki on modifiers: "When the derived verb is executed, the names u (and v, for a conjunction) are set with the values that were saved when the derived modifier was executed. If a u and v is a noun, the name m or n is also set. y (and x for a dyadic verb) are also set, and then the body of the derived verb is executed sentence by sentence." Thus, 1 {{ x + y }} 2, 1 {{ m + n }} 2, and 1 {{ u + v }} 2 will all produce 3.

I still don't get it. What's special about m that I can write 2 {{ 1 + m }} to get 3, but 2 {{ 1 + y }} doesn't work?

m is a left-hand operand, y is a right-hand argument. Try {{ 1 + y }} 2.

But isn't x also a left-hand operand? Why can't we write 2 {{ 1 + x }}? I haven't seen postfix execution take place anywhere else in the language except for adverbs.

{{ 1 + m }} is an adverb (the same part of speech as /).  u A, when A is an adverb and u is a noun or a verb, applies A to u.  an adverb always takes one operand on the left; a verb always takes either one argument on the right or two arguments on the left and right
